# Qt - How to use SQL SELECT COUNT with parameters?

Tags: qt, sqlite, qstring, qsqlquery, qsqldatabase

I'm writing a program in QT and have a problem with writing an SQL query Select.
I have a simple table which contains columns like: ID, name_or_nickname, surname, occupation. I have 3 variables I want to use in the query:

```
QString name = "Peter";
QString surname = "Smith"; 
QString occupation = "New York";
```

I want to run this query using those variables:

```
 QSqlDatabase sql;                                                 
 QSqlQuery query(sql);
 QString execute = "SELECT COUNT(name) FROM table1 WHERE name_or_nickname='?' AND surname='?' AND occupation='?';";
        query.prepare(execute);
        query.bindValue(0, name);
        query.bindValue(1, _surname);
        query.bindValue(2, _occupation);
        query.exec();

        if (query.next()) 
        {
            rows= query.value(0).toInt();
            return true;
        } 
        else 
        {
            qDebug() << query.lastError();
            return false;
        }
```

However it doesn't work and isActive() function returns false, so there's something wrong with the query - probably with the brackets. Could you show me an example how should I deal with it? Thank you in advance!

===========================================================================

## I post here the necessary code:

MainWindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <person.h>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QString>
#include <QtDebug>
#include <QtSql>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_1_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

    QSqlDatabase sql;
    bool open_or_not;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

MainWindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    sql = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE", "db");
    sql.setDatabaseName("E:\\folder\\database.sqlite3");
    sql.close(); // this was called beacuse of the problem with first query
    sql.open();

    QSqlQuery query(sql);
    QString execute = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1 (id INTEGER UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY, name_or_nickname TEXT, surname TEXT, occupation TEXT);";
query.exec(execute);
    qDebug() << "isActive: CREATING TABLE" << query.isActive();
    query.clear();

    open_or_not = sql.open();

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_1_clicked()
{
    if(open_or_not)
    {
        Person person1(_sql, Johnny, Walker, California, this);
        bool result = false;
        result = person1.search_in_database();
        qDebug() << result;
    }
}
```

Person.h:

```
#ifndef PERSON_H
#define PERSON_H

#include <QNetworkRequest>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QtDebug>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QJsonDocument>
#include <QtSql>

namespace Ui {
class Person;
}

class Person : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Person(QSqlDatabase & sql, QString name_or_nickname, QString surname, QString occupation, QWidget *parent);
    ~Person();

    bool search_in_table();

private:
    Ui::Person *ui;

    QSqlDatabase sql;
    QString name_or_nickname;
    QString surname;
    QString occupation;


};

#endif // PERSON_H
```

Person.cpp:

```
#include "person.h"
#include "ui_person.h"


Person::Person(QSqlDatabase & sql, QString name_or_nickname, QString surname, QString occupation, QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Person)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    this->sql = sql;
    this->name_or_nickname = name_or_nickname;
    this->surname = surname;
    this->occupation = occupation;

}

Person::~Person()
{
    delete ui;
}

bool Person::search_in_table()
{
    QSqlQuery query(sql);

    int rows = 0;
    QString name = this->name_or_nickname;
    QString _surname = this->surname;
    QString _occupation = this->occupation;

    QString execute = "SELECT COUNT(name) FROM table1 WHERE name_or_nickname='?' AND surname='?' AND occupation='?';";
    query.prepare(execute);
    query.bindValue(0, name);
    query.bindValue(1, _surname);
    query.bindValue(2, _occupation);
    query.exec();

    if (query.next()) 
    {
        rows= query.value(0).toInt();
        return true;
    } 
    else 
    {
        qDebug() << query.lastError();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Main.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Added missing brackets at the end of the line with QString execute, still doesn't work actually...

Comment: I see that you use `QSqlDatabase _sql;` But in what part do you set the configuration and open the connection?`

Comment: Well, I have 2 classes- MainWindow and Person. I set the configuration in the constructor of MainWindow and pass _sql parameter when creating objects of Person in MainWindow class. So I think everything should work fine

Comment: Well, as you did not point out in your question for me it is a point that can cause the error.

Comment: But what can cause this problem? I have even already tried passing this parameter by the reference, but it hasn't changed anything. Any other suggestions?

Comment: If the connection is not open you can not make any query, so my recommendation if you want help is that you provide a [mcve] and that you share the .db

Comment: I've updated the code - Please, take a look at the PS section at the bottom.

Comment: your code is not a [MCVE], please read the link so you understand what I mean

Comment: ok, just a moment, I'll do this

Comment: It took a moment for me, but I've uploaded the code.

Comment: change  `QSqlDatabase sql = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE", "db")` to `sql = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE", "db")`

Comment: Changed, still nothing happens...

Comment: okay, but that's a mistake since you're overlapping with a local variable that has the same name as an attribute of the class, I'm going to test your code in a moment

Comment: yes, there shouldn't be another declaration of sql variable

Comment: anyway- removing it hasn't helped neither :-(

Comment: what is search_in_database?

Comment: A part of my program- a method in which I search if an element exists in table and do some further operations, which are not important concerning this problem.

Comment: In what part of your code do you call search_in_table?

Comment: Actually, I have solved the problem. I do really appreciate your help. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better use query with parameters to prevent different type convertation issues in SQL

```
QString execute = "SELECT COUNT(name) FROM table1 WHERE surname=? AND occupation=?;";
QSqlQuery query;
query.prepare(execute);
query.bindValue(0, surname);
query.bindValue(1, occupation);
query.exec();
if (query.next()) {
    rows= query.value(0).toInt();
} else {
    qDebug() << query.lastError(); //check your error here
}
```

Comment: Well, I received this:
QSqlError("", "Parameter count mismatch", "")

Comment: What would you advise?

Comment: Query looks good... Maybe try to quote your field names. Like "SELECT COUNT('name')...". Maybe DBMS you use has system keyword called `name`

Comment: To be honest I just put the simple name of this variable, just to let you see how it work - the full name is: name_or_nickname, so I don't think DBMS can know this ;-) any other ideas?

Comment: Ok, I've solved the problem. Thank you very much for your help :-)

Answer (score 2):

**Try This Code :**

```
QSqlDatabase _sql;                                                 
QSqlQuery _query(_sql);
QString execute_stat = "SELECT COUNT(name) FROM table1 WHERE surname='%1' AND 
occupation='%2';";

_query.prepare(execute_stat.arg(surname, occupation));
q.exec();
int rows= 0;
if (q.next()) {
    rows= q.value(0).toInt();
}
```

Comment: It hasn't helped. isActive() still returns false :-( What else do you suggest?

Comment: you won't use isActive() to know the count of Name the count will be stored in rows variable

Comment: I know, I use it to see at first whether the query is all right

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to put double quotes at the end of the statement

Yours :

```
QString execute = "SELECT COUNT(name) FROM table1 WHERE surname='%1' AND occupation='%2';
```

Should Be :

```
QString execute = "SELECT COUNT(name) FROM table1 WHERE surname='%1' AND occupation='%2';"
```

Comment: Yeah, sure, but I made this mistake only here, on StackOverflow. In my program I have it. What do you sugest?

Comment: I added those brackets, but it doesn't work. What do you advise?

Comment: Ok, I've solved the problem. Thank you very much for your help :-)

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I don't know why neither of the suggested methods above did the job.

**However, the simpliest version worked for me:**

QString execute = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 WHERE (name_or_nickname='" + name + "') AND (surname='" + surname + "') AND (occupation='" + occupation + "');";

Thank you for all your help.